# How to recognize text at a steep angle with iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, computer-vision

I have a problem that involves recognizing text that is at any angle with the iPhone camera. I've attempted to use the Vision API and it works great for recognizing text that is either upright with respect to the camera, upside down or 90 degrees clockwise or counter-clockwise.

If the text is rotated outside of this range of quarter turns, say at 45 degrees, the Vision API consistently fails to find anything. Are there other APIs for iOS that would help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Vision API does not support deskewing. You can either perform the deskewing yourself(before the OCR) using other software like [OpenCV](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/) or use another OCR service that supports deskewing. For the second option you can use [Calamari](https://github.com/Calamari-OCR/calamari) or from [leadtools](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr?linkloc=grid) or [cloudmersive](https://cloudmersive.com/).

Comment: Since you mentioned our SDK as a possible solution, we’d like to add that it has a free, fully-functional, time-limited evaluation [that can be downloaded from this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=apple#apple). The evaluation includes free support through email and online chat.